# Create a custom $form_id for a webform integrated into a node?

Tags: webforms

I have used Webform many times before but this is the first time I am testing Webform Node :

> Provides a Webform content type which allows webforms to be integrated
> into a website as nodes.

Usually, I integrate webforms with blocks.

Everything works fine but I notice that the webform `$form_id` contains the node id (here `nid = 174`):

```
webform_submission_shop_contact_node_174_add_form
```

This poses a problem for me because I want to make a hook to add a library. The hook will therefore not be able to work on all environments once deployed because here the node is content and the nid will be different.

In `hook_form_alter`

```
if ($form_id === 'webform_submission_shop_contact_node_174_add_form') {
    $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'custom_theme/contact';
}
```

Do you know if I can modify the id of this webform integrated into a node?

I saw this option here `/admin/structure/webform/manage/{webform}/settings/form`

[image]

which allows you to create a custom id but this has no effect (probably because the webform is integrated into a node).

Comment: Are you looking for the base form ID, `webform_submission_shop_contact_form` in your case, or the webform ID `shop_contact`?

Comment: Thanks @4uk4 , I hadn't even thought to look at this solution. if I do `dump($form)`, I can clearly see the `#webform_id` key : `shop_contact`. I can now add my library like this in `hook_form_alter` : `if (isset($form['#webform_id']) && $form['#webform_id'] === 'shop_contact') { ... }` So simple, it works. Do you want to answer the question so I can vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a breakpoint in a form alter hook I see at least two ways to get the info you are looking for:

```
$form['#webform_id']
```

or the base form ID (without the node details) in

```
$form_state->getBuildInfo()
```

in your case `webform_submission_shop_contact_form`, which can also be used in `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`.